# Xcode 5 Toolbar Buttons Not Working

Tags: xcode, toolbars

I'm having an issue after installing Xcode 5. The toolbar buttons to show/hide the Assistant Editor and the Version Editor are not working. They don't respond at all; I have to access those functions from the menu.

Also, the buttons to show/hide the navigation, debug and utilities pane are not working. The tool tips work, they just don't respond to clicks.

Anyone else having this issue?

I get OS X 10.8.5 and XCode 5.0. I made upgrade from Xcode 4.6 and I never installed any beta version.

Comment: May sounds silly, but, have you tried rebooting your Mac?

Comment: @Benoit, yes. Twice times at least :)

Comment: When you launch Xcode or attempt to click on the buttons, does Console.app show anything in the logs that seems fishy and does Activity Monitor show any CPU usage by Xcode?

Comment: @Benoit. I dont' know what happen, but it's working again. I think maybe was related to another error that I have with the upgrade. I will close the question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Benoit The problem I don't know why is working again !! :)

Comment: Got same problem, when I open a workspace, I receive message says  there are some error in storyboard will be auto fix, and the toolbar not working. At the same time, toolbar works in other project without the message. After fixing the error, the toolbar works again!

Comment: @yhlin How did you fixed the error in your storyboard? Was it automatically after your save the Storyboard?

Comment: I select auto fix(I forgot detail wording)let Xcode fix for me. After reopen Xcode twice, The error message never show up, and toolbar works again.

Comment: @yhlin Thanks for your data but I don't have same luck with the inconsistency error.

Comment: It's Xcode 8 now. This bug is still present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@yhlin and @benoit have partially reason.

The problem appear after you receive a error message when you open the Storyboard ([Storyboard Internal Inconsistencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967190/storyboard-internal-inconsistencies)), then I opened the storyboard file (via TextEdit) and then the toolbar does not work, but, after a restart the Xcode (or even the Mac completely) works everything fine again.

I believe is a minor bug in the XCode 5.0. or an upgrade issue, but apparently is not a big thing.

UPDATE ***
After installing Mavericks and Xcode 5.0.1 the problem was fixed.

Comment: This is not minor, this is reallllly annoying as it is something we use on a frequent basis when designing an app. Neither a restart does not fix the problem, nor a full reboot. This answer should not be accepted. I think Apple do not test its products properly ! As an intensive user, seeing so many bugs on XCODE 5 is simply not acceptable.

Comment: @ChristopheFondacci Definitely my answer is not a final solution, is just a workaround. I hope the next Xcode version arrives with final fix.

Answer (score 16):

This has been happening to me after every reboot since upgrading to Xcode 5.

The workaround I have been using is:

1. Close the project but leave Xcode open.
2. Open another project.
3. Close it.
4. Reopen the original project - inactive toolbar buttons should now be active.

Comment: Solved my issue, Thanks you! Screen real-estate is limited on a 13" and my show/hide buttons weren't responding.

Comment: Yes, not an obvious solution but glad it helped.

Comment: This still is the way for XCode 7 (beta) :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue. Until Apple addresses it I'll just be using keyboard shortcuts (option+command+return to show assistant editor, command+return to show standard editor). Maybe I'll just abandon the toolbar buttons altogether. :)

Comment: Thanks for the keyboard shortcut, the only quick and viable workaround we got so far...

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issues even after upgrading to Mavericks and Xcode 5.0.1. This problem as well as other project crippling bugs in the new release of Xcode (5.0) can be temporarily worked-around by restarting Xcode, opening a different project, closing that project then opening the project you wanted to work with. Sorry for the crude fix but it works for me so I thought I'd share.

NOTE:
This won't fix the IOKit.framework error, the best fix for that is going into terminal and performing the following commands:

> cd/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework
>   sudo ln -s Versions/A/IOKit

Answer (score 1):

Just providing input to this topic.  I had this problem and none of the above solutions were helping, turns out a tap gesture recognizer I had over the toolbar was disabling all the buttons on the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem.  I have OS 10.10 Yosemite Beta and Xcode 5.1.1

For me, none of the previous answers helped me.  The issue fix for me was to take xcode out of full screen mode. If it's in full screen mode it will not work, but as soon as I take it out of full screen, it works just fine.